# Prove that if $\sum_1^\infty a_n$ converges provided $a_n>0$ for all $n$, then $\sum_1^\infty \sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}$ converges too

Tags: calculus

I wrote $b_n:=\sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}$ and tried to apply a few tests on the series. Here are the tests that didn't work:

$$b_n<=a_n$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{b_n}{a_n}$$

$$\lim_{n\to\infty} {b_{n+1}}{b_n}$$

$$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}<=\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that since all the terms are positive we have
$$\sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}} \leq \dfrac{a_n + a_{n+1}}2$$
Hence, we have
$$\sum_{n=1}^N \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}} \leq \dfrac12\left(\sum_{n=1}^Na_n + \sum_{n=1}^N a_{n+1}\right) = \sum_{n=1}^N a_n + \dfrac{a_{N+1}-a_1}2$$
Now make use of the fact that $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$ converges and that $\lim_{N \to \infty} a_N = 0$ to conclude what you want.

Infact, we are able to show a slightly stronger claim that the series  $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} \sqrt{a_na_{n+1}}$ converges to a number smaller than $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n$, since $a_1 > 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Cauchy Schwarz:

$$ \left( \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}} \right)^2 \leq \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_n \cdot \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} a_{n+1}$$

Answer (score 0):

By AM-GM inequality $\sqrt{a_n a_{n+1}} < \frac{a_n +a_{n+1}}{2}$